# My excel 2010 will not allow me to do charts

Tags: microsoft-excel

I cannot get my 2010 Excel to do charts.  The whole section under insert is not highlighted except under tables.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] you question to add some detail to it. What have you tried? Was this an existing file or one you just created? Is this a trusted document in the trust center? Are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: see if this helps: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/unable-to-view-modify-or-create-charts-in-excel/01012a94-a3ae-431a-9778-5cfad5e1fc76

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple worksheets selected? Shift click a single worksheet and see if that fixes it.
Is track changes enabled? Click Review tab, click Track Changes and deactivate it.
Another possible issue, though not very common:
File > options > advanced > Display Options for this workbook: For Objects Show All